# Can manufacturers make it an IP tort to connect to their machines?

Tags: united-states, intellectual-property

Can manufacturers block other manufacturers from making parts that connect to their machines?

For example, ultrasound machines have two parts, a console and a transducer. The transducers usually connect to the console via a proprietary connector interface.

Can a third party manufacturer sell a competing transducer that connects to the interface?

Or, to take a more familiar example. IBM computer keyboards and mice used to connect to the PC via a connector called a PS2 connector. Imagine IBM patented the PS2 connector. Would that have prevented anyone else from making a peripheral that connects to a PS2 port on an IBM PC?

Comment: Where?  The answer will not be the same world-wide.

Comment: @MartinBonner sorry, updated tags

Comment: Some printers use data signals to prevent 3rd party ink, and I recall them using the DCMA to protect the signals. Which to me implies those printer manufactures couldn't just use a proprietary plug, since it would be much cheaper to make a plastic plug in a (slightly) different shape then add chips to ink cartridges.

Comment: The cases are a mix of patent law and anti-trust law. I don't personally know how they come out.